# What's the eclipse preferences file format? Can I delete arbitrary lines in prefs.epf?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using knime, an eclipse product.  After having exported the eclipse preferences, I want to keep only some essential settings for system tests.

But when I delete some lines in my preferences.epf file, it seems that it won't get re-imported correctly by eclipse/knime.

At the first glance, the epf file format seems like a plain ini file without any hierarchical structure, is this correct?  Is there any epf format specification?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It is a Java Properties file. I don't think there is any documentation on the format other than reading the source code.

Answer (score 0):

As +greg-449 commented, the answer is "it depends." Past the storage format itself, it depends on whatever's going to try to use those values when they're imported as to how it will react to selective deletions. The best thing to do is to see if you can select just the parts of your Preferences you want to keep during the Export itself.

Comment: Ok, so the real problem is not the epf format, but how the information given in the epf is handled, and whether there might be internal dependencies between epf entries.

Comment: Exactly. How what's represented there is organized is up to whomever authored the plug-ins involved.